# Help with SharePoint Customer and Project sites directory, listing

Tags: directory

hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I’m looking to make some sort of directory system.

What we want is,    we need a Site for each of our customers, and from there will be a handful of sub sites for Tenders to that customer, which then need to change into projects once the tender is successful.

For this we need a top level Directory, that can list the customer sites based on industry practice,    and also, separately, list ALL project sites, splits by their stage (Tender, Project, Complete, etc.)

I’m really struggling to find a solution to this.

I’ve no experience with Visual Studio solutions, so really need something I can achieve OTB, I’m very happy using custom Workflows in Designer though.

I first though of using the Search Core Results webparts to display the sites by using some sort of metadata,    but I’m struggling to figure out how to attach that metadata directly to the site.

I also thought of using a workflow to manage a prebuilt Index on the top level site of each Customer and Project site, which I think I could work,   but it requires that people fill in details correctly by consistently using the correct customer name when creating projects sites from that company (too many people have the horrible habit of using initials,  or in some places using 'Limited' in others 'Ltd' or sometime not at all for the same customer)  so I would prefer to find a way to do things automatically,  which could maybe get the parent site name automatically maybe.

If anyone has any ideas, recommendations of places to look, or anything at all that could help I would really appreciate it, Thanks.

ps, we currently use SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, and really want a solution that will migrate to 2013.

Comment: Without some custom coding, I will doubt that is possible (maybe cause its my comfort zone)..